# Collect stress test data in openstack

Tags: stress-testing, openstack

i've installed openstack essex edition in a single-node, using stackops. For my thesis, i have to do some test on the performance of openstack.

I need a stress test to test openstack system and an application that's can represent these test with some graphics...

it's possible? anyone can help me?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the [OpenStack integration testing documentation](http://qa.openstack.org/integration.html). In particular, there's a test suite called [Tempest](https://github.com/openstack/tempest) which is used for OpenStack integration testing, and includes [stress tests](https://github.com/openstack/tempest/tree/master/stress).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/cloudscaling/tarkin  This is something we've worked with in the past to do some VERY rudimentary load testing.

Answer (score 0):

For the swift(storage) component we use [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/) to make some load and stress tests.Tsung also gives graphical reports.